# Vote to close as off-topic or flag for migration?

Tags: discussion, flags, migration

I see a lot of questions on Stack Overflow that are not programming questions and would be more appropriate for [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).

I usually vote to close such questions as off-topic, with a custom explanation suggesting Ask Ubuntu. (Often other users have voted to migrate the same question to [superuser](https://superuser.com/), probably because it's easier.)

(I would like to see automatic migration to more sites, but that's already been covered elsewhere and it's not what this question is about.)

Should I vote to close such questions (leaving it up to the questioner to repost and *eventually* for the question to be closed and deleted on SO), or should I flag it for moderator attention and ask for it to be migrated?  Voting to close avoids imposing extra work on the moderators, but flagging is a more direct way to achieve the desired outcome of moving the question to the appropriate site.

(Most such questions would also be topical on superuser or on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), but in the cases I'm thinking of Ask Ubuntu is a better fit.)

[Here's a recent example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38646403/827263).

Mike McCaughan raises a good point: it probably matters whether the question would be closed on the other site (for example, if it's very likely to be a duplicate). For purposes of this question, please assume that the question in question (!) would be appropriate for the other site.

Comment: Well, the real question is if it would be closed on the other site, right? I would think a question like that would have been asked already...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: Good point. If a question is likely to be closed even on the more appropriate site, it's probably better to vote to close and suggest looking for duplicates before posting. On the other hand, sometimes the question is appropriate for the other site. It's not "the real question", it's a different (and related) question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you find a question that you think belongs elsewhere on the network, there are a few things to ask:

1. What is the quality of the question?
2. Is it off-topic on SO and on-topic on another site?

Moderators typically follow the rule don't migrate crap, so the answer to the first question is pretty important.

If you run across a question that isn't low-quality and it's off-topic for SO, but on-topic for another site, then feel free to flag it for moderator attention asking them to migrate it.

If it's a low-quality question, then just vote to close it.  Moderators won't migrate it even if it's on-topic on another site.